# Who and what am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> I went to the moon
>   You followed me there
>   I once played a tune
>   You followed me here
>   Now it's all runes
>   You follow me everywhere

Hint A (harder):

> Mice fly among sea, shadow, and sky.

Hint B (easier):

> [*click here*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/74694)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE @DiscreteGames!

Comment: Will it take any specific, trivia-ish knowledge to figure out this riddle?

Comment: @BrentHackers Maybe for parts of it. Though I think many people would readily understand it all.

Comment: @DiscreteGames looks like you linked to a dead link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question doesn't have the [trivia](/questions/tagged/trivia) tag, but maybe the answer could still be

> [Link](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Link), the protagonist in the [Legend of Zelda](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/The_Legend_of_Zelda_(Series)) video game series.

I went to the moon
You followed me there

> In the game [Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Majora%27s_Mask), we get to follow Link, as he does indeed go to the moon at one point.

I once played a tune

> While Link plays several woodwind instruments during the series, this would probably be a reference to the [Ocarina of Time](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Ocarina_of_Time), the 5th game in the series.

You followed me here

> "here" as in to this webpage. Yes, I followed a link to get here.

Now it's all runes

> Runes are a game mechanic in the latest (19th!) instalment in the series, [Breath of the Wild](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Breath_of_the_Wild).

You follow me everywhere

> Again with the web page links, just like in the easier hint, maybe?

Disclaimer: I have never actually played any of those games, this answer is 99% google-fu, so I have no answer to the difficult clue.

Comment: This is all correct! Sorry about the lack of trivia tag, didn't realize it might need it.

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> Armstrong

I went to the moon
You followed me there

> Neil Armstrong went to the moon

I once played a tune
You followed me here

> Louis Armstrong, famed trumpeter

Now it's all runes
You follow me everywhere

> Bit of a stretch, but possible [Alex Louis Armstrong](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Alex_Louis_Armstrong) from Full Metal Alchemist, which heavily features runes in the lore

Other possibility (without a third answer):

> Buzz - Buzz Aldrin, Buzz as in the musical tone, but no third answer yet for that option

Comment: I like where you're going with rot13(ohmm) and I hope you are right. Maybe the third answer is because rot13(ohmm pna zrna cbchyne, naq cbchyne guvatf ner sbyybjrq rireljurer? Eharf vf n ovg bqq, ohg znlor vg unf gb qb jvgu orvat jevggra nobhg bayvar.)

Comment: Yeah I just don't know enough about runes (in any context really) to seek out any useful synonyms or general knowledge references.

Comment: Good guess but incorrect. The "follow" parts don't quite fit in.

Answer (score 1):

New answer, after the comment that I'm wrong (so sad):
Are you

> This riddle, or the person who wrote it
> You went to the moon in the writing, and I followed along, I followed you 'here' where 'here' is the word itself, and the riddle is runes (letters) and I followed you throughout it. This time, the line stumping me is the tune. Perhaps because the riddle is a rhyming set of lines?

Old answers:

Are you

> Ambition 
>  Ambition is what has driven humanity to set sights on the moon in the 1900s. It is like the tune that the sailors in *The Odyssey* heard the sirens sing, since it is like an instinctual call that cannot be resisted. The runes/everywhere part has me a bit more confused but it could have something to do with thirst for knowledge and the ambition to know everything, so we read up on a diverse set of information.

I know this is a bit weak, but I had to shoot for something reasonable after giving the below answer.

My previous joking answer, which ignored half of your riddle:

> Unless you're Peter Pan, your shadow follows you everywhere.

Comment: Both incorrect. You may be thinking too hard ;)

Comment: Your new answer is also incorrect, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it this time. The answer is

> Eagle

Moon:

> The Eagle Has Landed

Tune:

> The Eagles

Rune:

> The Eagle has become a symbol and can be found in a lot of places (dollar bill, etc...)

Comment: Nice idea but nope once again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite have a full answer, but I think it is

> links

I went to the moon, You followed me there

> I'm not sure about this one. A spacecraft containing code presumably landed on the moon before humans did, but did it contain links?. I might be missing something here.

I once played a tune

> There is an R&B singer named link

you followed me here

> you probably clicked a link to get to this page

Now it's all runes

> links are made up of letters and numbers and symbols

You follow me everywhere

> You use links to navigate around the internet

Hint A

> Mice fly among sea, shadow, and sky.
> Mice = computer mice. Sea, shadow and sky could mean the colors of links depending on their state. Sea = new link (dark blue), Shadow = clicked link (purple) and Sky = hovered over link (light blue)

Hint B

> literally a link

Answer (score 0):

You are

> SOUND? or SHADOW?

I went to the moon You followed me there

> astronauts were able to hear sounds on the moon because vibrations would transmit through the surface of the moon, on up through their suits, to the air in the suits and so be heard

I once played a tune You followed me here

> Tune characterizes a certain piece of music. When you play tune, sound will follow you.

Now it's all runes You follow me everywhere

> Runes are the letters in a set of **related alphabets** known as runic alphabets, which were used to write various Germanic languages before the adoption of the Latin alphabet and for specialized purposes thereafter. **May runes and letters sound same**..?

Comment: Nope. Getting a bit too contrived.

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer

> AM Radio

Moon:

> People listened to the moon landing on the radio.

Tune:

> Music used to be broadcast over AM

Rune:

> Rune can refer to something unrecognizable to today's generation.

Comment: Incorrect, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

> The Pied Piper!

Moon:

> the Pied Piper was written by Uncle Moon

Tune:

> the Pied Piper plays a tune (and you follow him)

Rune:

> It's an old story and all that is left of it are the words (runes) that comprise it

Comment: Again, sadly incorrect.

Comment: Darn, thought I had it that time :/